# Could someone check if this proof is correct? Thanks.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence with limit $a$ and let $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be an injective mapping. For n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ we define $b_n=a_{\sigma(n)}$. Prove that $b_n$ also converges to $a$.

Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$. We know: $$\forall\varepsilon>0.\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge n_0:|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$$
Therefore for any of $a_n, a_{n+1},...$ we have $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$

We define $c_n=a_1, a_2,...,a_{n-1}.$ There exist (or not, we'll discuss this case later) numbers in c, such that $|c_{n_0}-a|\ge\varepsilon$. Let this set be $A$. We know from before: $$b_n=\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3,...$$

There are 2 cases:

1) $\forall \alpha \in A:\alpha \notin b_n$ $\Longrightarrow$ every member of $b_n$ is close enough to the limit.

2) $\exists \alpha \in A:\alpha \in b_n$

Now let $B=\{ \alpha; \alpha \in A \land \alpha \in b_n\}$

Then we can choose a suitable $\alpha \in B: \forall b \in b_n:(\sigma_m=b \land \sigma_k=\alpha \Longrightarrow m<k)$

We then have:
$$\forall n>k:|a_{\sigma_n}-a|<\varepsilon$$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I fixed it now.

Comment: Fixed another error.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof has some issues with it. First, you don't use your $n_0$ anywhere (and you should). Second, I don't see where you use injectivity of $\sigma$, and that is a necessary step.

The fixes aren't too difficult. You know that for $n\ge n_0$ we have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon.$ Use injectivity of $\sigma$ to show that there is some $m_0$ such that $\sigma_m\ge n_0$ for $m\ge m_0$. At that point, recalling the definition of $b_m,$ you're basically done.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your suggestions into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you better prove and make use of: There are only finitely many $n$ with $\sigma(n)\le n_0$.